# Recorrer un bucle for aplicando un operador lógico o estableciendo diferentes opciones

Tags: python

Quiero recorrer una carpeta y seleccionar todas las imágenes que hay dentro de esta. Por ahora tengo lo siguiente,

```
import glob

image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('screen/*.jpg'):
    image_list.append(filename)
```

Es decir, soy capaz de obtener todas las imágenes `.jpg` (obviamente si en cambio la extensión, pues capaz de obtener todas las de dicha extensión). La cosa es que en esta carpeta también tengo imagénes `.png`, ¿és posible en un bucle `for` poner dos opciones, o un operador `or`? Ahora lo he solucionado así, pero estoy seguro que se puede simplificar/optimizar.

```
import glob

image_list = []
for filename in glob.glob('screen/*.jpg'):
    image_list.append(filename)
for filename in glob.glob('screen/*.png'):
    image_list.append(filename)
```

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568580/python-glob-multiple-filetypes#4568638

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías recorrer toda la carpeta y usar el condicional `if` usando el módulo `os` (no es necesario instalarlo, viene por defecto con Python):

```
import os

image_list = []
for filename in os.listdir('screen'):
    if '.jpg' in filename or '.png' in filename:
         image_list.append(filename)
```

La función `os.listdir()` le pasamos un *path*, y nos da todo lo que contiene ese *path*, es como hacer un `ls` en Linux o un `dir` en Windows.

Una vez tenemos con la función, todos los archivos que hay en el directorio, simplemente seleccionamos aquellos que nos interesen, en este caso los `.jpg` y los `.png`

Comment: He ampliado la contestación a esta pregunta como **wiki de la comunidad** [¿Cómo recorrer carpetas, subcarpetas y ficheros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398988/c%c3%b3mo-recorrer-carpetas-subcarpetas-y-ficheros-en-python)